# How can I force my Google chrome account to update my bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks

I use three different computers and sign in to each one with the same Google Chrome account, but the bookmarks do not seem to be updating.  For example I add a bookmark when signed in on one pc, then open chrome on one of the other pc and it is not there, is there a way to force it to update the bookmarks and histrory etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bit of a delay to be sure. As it will go and fetch the details from google.

In the past all I had to do was open this URL in Chrome and make sure the settings are correct: chrome://settings/syncSetup

Click OK
And close all Chrome windows and reopen the application

Sometimes I get prompted for my encryption password, but after that it syncs.